# Query building in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have been learning Entity Framework Core for about two weeks. I kind of understand how to use it. But when it comes to querying. The query that'is generated from LINQ looks so crazy. It has so many unnecessary duplicated left joins. I cant post my query here and have people help me to optimise it. But I want to know are there a documentation or some article that I can read to understand how queries are generated from LINQ. And all the ways to optimize one query at LINQ level not talking about indexing and stuff related to database.

Comment: Query translation is quite complicated process and in EF Core is modified with every release. You won't find documentation for that.

Comment: This seems more of a GitHub question than a SO one. You might get some more concrete help from the EF team if you post this there. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: Thank you. I will try to ask on github repo of EF core.